# How to fix index.d.ts error of d3-dag while building Angular application

Tags: javascript, css, angular, d3.js, d3-dag

I have running Angular 12 application and I have installed d3 and d3-dag to create graphs. But I am getting errors in node_modules/d3-dag....index.d.ts file.

Angular version: 12.2.16
Node.js version: 14.16.1
d3 version: 7.8.5
d3-dag version: 1.1.0

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "dev": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json --live-reload true",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production --aot --output-hashing none --vendor-chunk=true",
    "install-dependencies": "npm install && npm install ../../../../bin/node_modules/mi-diagnostics-0.0.1.tgz --no-save",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/common": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "12.2.16",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "6.0.2",
    "@shui/core": "1.14.0-hotfix2-ie.1",
    "@types/d3": "^7.4.3",
    "d3": "^7.8.5",
    "d3-dag": "^1.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/estree": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/d3": "^7.4.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.2",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
```

}

**dag.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as d3dag from 'd3-dag';
import { IJobGraphNode, JobGraphNodeType } from './dag-data.model';
import { getNodeStateString, getNodeTypeString } from '../utils/dag-helpers';
import { initialData } from './dag-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dag-graph-viewer',
  templateUrl: './dag-graph-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dag-graph-viewer.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class DagGraphViewerComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  jgData: IJobGraphNode[] | null = null;
  builder: d3dag.DefaultStratify;
  nodeRadius = 20;
  nodeSize = [this.nodeRadius * 2, this.nodeRadius * 2] as const;
  zoom: any;
  height: number = 0;
  width: number = 0;
  }
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "../Client",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

When I am trying to build angular application, I am getting error as below:

[image]

Comment: Your screen shot of the error cuts off the most important part...   Instead of screen shotting why not cut and paste it in its **entirety** into the question?